# Почему glob.glob не хочет читать папку с "[...]" в адресе?

Tags: python, glob

Запускаю вот такой скрипт:

```
import glob

folder_with_files_address = input("Enter folder address: ") + "\*.mkv"
print(folder_with_files_address)

for video_path in glob.glob(folder_with_files_address):
    print(video_path)
```

Если в input запускаю нечто вроде `c:\1 2`, то glob все обрабатывает и выдает мне принтом список mkv внутри папки.

Если же я переименую папку в `c:\1 2 [3]`, то скрипт выведет мне вот такой вывод:

```
C:/test/main.py
Enter folder address: C:\1 2 [3]
C:\1 2 [3]\*.mkv
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Почему glob не хочет обрабатывать папку с [...] в названии?
Можно ли как то сделать, чтобы он смог?

Comment: Оу, спасибо! Сделаю так!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### И так, glob.

> The glob module finds all the pathnames matching a specified pattern **according to the rules used by the Unix shell**
> Модуль glob находит все пути, соответствующие указанному шаблону, **в соответствии с правилами, используемыми оболочкой Unix**

Следуя правилам Unix, получаем, что `[]` используются для создания групп символов.
Например, путь `/home/user/file[123B]` будет включать в себя файлы:

```
/home/user/file1
/home/user/file2
/home/user/file3
/home/user/fileB
```

Значит строка `c:\1 2 [3]` интерпритируется как `c:\1 2 3` и конечно не находит нужной папки.

---

### Что делать?

- Можно экранировать квадратную скобку, заменив ее на `[[]` (группа, которая содержит один символ - открывающую квадратную скобку).
  То есть путь, представленный выше можно переписасть как: `/home/user/file[[]123B]`. Открывающая скобка экранирована, закрывающая без открывающей не работает. Теперь мы получим только один файл -

```
/home/user/file[123B]
```

- Чтобы сделать это автоматически, можно использовать метод [glob.escape()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.escape). Он сам выполнит экранирование всех спецсимолов (`*?[`)

---

Конкретно ваш пример я бы переписал так:

```
import glob

folder_with_files_address = glob.escape(input("Enter folder address: ")) + r"\*.mkv"
#прибавляю путь со звездочкой после вызова escape(), иначе она бы оказалось экранирована
print(folder_with_files_address)

for video_path in glob.glob(folder_with_files_address):
    print(video_path)
```

Answer (score 3):

Потому, что это специальные символы (как `*` и `?`), и в квадратных скобочках перечисляются символы которые могут быть на этом месте. Об этом написано в первом абзаце [документации на glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html).

Просто пишите `[[]` и `[]]` для `[` и `]` соответственно.
Или используйте функцию `glob.escape()` чтобы проэкранировать все спец.символы во введённой строке.

```
folder_with_files_address = glob.escape(input("Enter folder address: ")) + "\*.mkv"
```

Comment: Я расписал то же решение немного подробнее, не сочтите за плагиат`:)`